# Creating 2D arrays using new Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was trying out a question on Hackerrank where I needed to create an array of array (basically 2d arrays).

My go-to one liner would be `const counter = new Array(4).fill([])`
However, I realized that it would create a 2D array but applying any function to the array would cause it to apply to all the elements.

```js
let count = new Array(4).fill([])
count[0].push("Test")
console.log(JSON.stringify(count))
```

The outcome would be all the sub-arrays having the same value of "Test" inside them.

The final solution would be:

```js
let count = Array.from(Array(4), () => new Array());
count[0].push("Test")
console.log(JSON.stringify(count))
```

May I ask the reason why it's not working as expected?

Comment: I am not getting what is the issue you are having?

Comment: If you have the solution, then what's the problem now?

Comment: Because you're filling all the arrays with the reference to the same array.

Comment: `.fill([])` will set all elements in the array to a reference to the array passed into fill, whereas with array.from, you're mapping each element to its own array instance

Comment: The question is the answer.  Arrays are referenced, not copied, when passed around.

Comment: Object's in JS are referenced, array happen to be objects too.  So `var a = {x: 1}, b = a; b.x = 2;`  Here `a.x` will end up being 2. Referenced object in JS can be tricky, but once you understand that one-liner, it becomes a lot clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.fill()` takes the argument and, if it's an object, it copies the reference to that object into every index of the new array. Since in fact `[]` is an object, your new array ends up being filled with references to the same array.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

> If the first parameter is an object, it will copy its reference and fill the array with references to that object.

Comment: Does it make a shallow copy though? Doesn't it just put a direct reference to the argument, with no shallow copy?

Comment: After seeing your edit, my comment stands: that doesn't say it makes a shallow copy, that says it copies the reference -- it's not a shallow copy at all

Comment: @TKoL you're right, I was thinking too fast. I've updated my answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: yeah! it's better now

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Array(4).fill([])`, you are actually filling count with only **one** array (`[]`). All the elements inside `count` refer to the same array. This is why when you alter the first element (which is also referenced by the second, third, and fourth element) and print `count`, `count`'s elements all have the same array object. *The same referencing scenario in fill happens to all objects, not just arrays.*

Here, you can see that the second, third, and fourth element refers (denoted by `/**ref:2**/`) to the object with the same `id` (`/**id:2**/`) as the first element:

```js
let count = new Array(4).fill([])
count[0].push("Test")
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        .fill([]) | New Array
       +----------+------+------+------+------+
       |          |      |      |      |      |
Memory |    []    |indx0 |indx1 |indx2 |indx3 |
       |          |      |      |      |      |
       +----------+------+------+------+------+
            ^        |      |      |      |   
            |        |      |      |      |   
            +--------+      |      |      |   
            +---------------+      |      |
            +----------------------+      |
            +-----------------------------+
```

The four indexes are pointing to the same value in memory, so when you're pushing an element, you're doing on the same value (array) in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain:

```
let count = new Array(4).fill([])
```

Here you create just 2 arrays actually. one is `[]` and second contains 4 links to `[]`.

In other words you are creating an array of 4 links to the **single** instance of array.

--

```
let count = Array.from(Array(4), () => new Array());
```

Here you create 5 different arrays. 4 different empty `[]` and array that contains 4 links, one link to each unique `[]`.

In other words here you create array filled with a different arrays